# Problem with hearing singing voice different than the outcome

Tags: voice, beginner

I have been trying to learn a bit of singing starting last month, but I'm not getting anywhere. I have the problem that the things I sing in my head sound fine to me, but I know for a fact from feedback that it sounds horrible and is super off key to people hearing it. I hear different tones in my head than the ones I actually produce.
Is that a known problem, and does anyone know how to fix it?
I tried singing along to my tuner, and according to that my voice is just very loud background noise and doesn't have notes.

Comment: Have you tried recording yourself and listening to it?

Comment: Additional reference: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/69824/do-out-of-tune-singers-hear-that-theyre-off

Comment: Somehow I can't really trust your tuner that saying your voice is just very loud background noise *and doesn't have notes*, unless you're really singing too loud/close to the tuner, or you're really making some kind of percussion-like/noise sounds. Try humming (e.g. a constant note) instead and see if the tuner catches it, or if it's broken.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica You should make that an answer!

Answer (score 4):

As ever - find a teacher! Not easy right now, I understand, but hopefully soon.

A tuner isn't tangible enough. You need an instrument. Yes, it may incur some extra learning, but at the end, the benefits outweigh the struggles.

A cheap keyboard will be beneficial, as you will find your way round it quite quickly. Play a note, sing it. Record what you do, so you can hear both the played and sung notes, for comparison. Most people are not tone deaf. It might just be that you are in the minority, but that's doubtful. keep playing and singing a few notes each day, and listen to the improvement.